# I was using the pandas module(Just starting with python) and when I was running the code It is showing runtime error. What should I do

Tags: python-3.x

```
import pandas as pd
series1 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4])
print(series1)
```

#This shows runtime error in pandas module

Comment: Works perfectly in my computer. Please post the full error traceback.

Comment: Works perfectly too. pls post your error

Comment: Well I don't know how to share the problem with you. But can you tell me how to solve runtime error in python as when I am using the matplotlib module it is also showing runtime error.